# How to get webform url object, if I have webform machine name and webform path

Tags: webforms, 9, uri

I have webform path and webform machine name, how can I get url object of this webform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same route as for other entities: `$webform_url = Url::fromRoute('entity.webform.canonical', ['webform' => 'my_webform_id']);`

Comment: This is NOT a [Symfony route object](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/6.2/Route.php), this is a [Drupal\Core\Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/10) object. If this is the accepted answer, then the question is about URL objects, not route objects.

Comment: @Hudri Edited the question due to your remark.